# Laravel - group the record based on similar id in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, group-by

How to group the table records based on similar id in Laravel
For Example:
in mysql  products table  have folllowing records with similar cat id
 Table name: products

```
id:1 pro_name:xyz1 cat_id:55
id:2 pro_name:xyz2 cat_id:22
id:3 pro_name:xyz3 cat_id:55
id:4 pro_name:xyz4 cat_id:22
```

What I am trying to do is for similar cat_id it should make its array. I Try to use

```
    $all = Products::groupBy('cat_id')->get();
```

But its displaying only first record of each similar cat_id.

output I am getting:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pro_name": "xyz1",
    "cat": "55",
    "created_at": "2017-02-09 13:09:13",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-18 11:56:04"
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
    "pro_name": "xyz2",
    "cat": "22",
    "created_at": "2017-02-22 06:04:23",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-22 06:04:23"
  }
```

I want that it should display all record of similar id in an array
Help me for this

Comment: can you share the desired result.

Comment: Can use GROUP_CONCAT , but to get in same array you need to run a separate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by summarises your table, using the parameters given (hence it is only showing the first one, and in Naincy's answer, a total is calculated for the grouped elements).

Perhaps you are looking for Order By?

```
$info = DB::table('Products')
     ->orderBy('cat_id')
     ->get();
```

You will get the results from the whole table, sorted by the `cat_id`, and will have to detect when a category changes manually.

Another alternative is to get the distinct cat_id's, and then run your own query on them. You could encapsulate the code in the model or a repository. Note, this will run a number of queries on your database, which might not be preferable.

```
//Create an array
$groups = []

//Retrieve the list of cat_id's in use.
$cats = DB::table('Products')->distinct()->select('cat_id')->get()

//for each cat_id in use, find the products associated and then add a collection of those products to the relevant array element
foreach($cats as $cat){
    $groups[$cat->cat_id] = DB::table('Products')->where('cat_id', $cat->cat_id)->get();
}
```

Note: My only concern with what you are doing here is that you are really looking for relationships? If you used [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), all of this becomes very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code...

```
$row = Products::selectRaw("pro_name,cat_id")->groupBy("cat_id","pro_name")->get();
            
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
$info = DB::table('Products')
         ->select('cat_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 
             DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(pro_name) AS product_name"))
         ->groupBy('cat_id')
         ->get();
```

Comment: It showing output as ` {
    "cat_id": "22",
    "total": "2"
  },
  {
   "cat_id": "55",
    "total": "2"
  },` @Naincy

Comment: Yes it shows that for cat_id you have 2 records and for 55 also you have 2 records

Comment: But I want all the fields not total. @Naincy

Comment: if you will do group by it will not give you columns.....then you need to read about proper usage of group by.

Comment: If you want only product names by grouping categories then you can use group_concat and later in php you can explode them with ,
updated my answer too